# Multiple functions with button by changing class fails after changing class once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form and want to switch between the login and register easily. I have it set so that if the user clicks register the register form shows and that button changes to a button that will take them back to the login form if desired.

However when the user goes back to the login form, it won't let them get back to the register form again.

```js
$('.register-form').hide();

$('a.register').click(function() {
  $('.login-form').hide();
  $('.register-form').show();
  
  $('button').text('Register');
  $('a.register').removeClass('register').addClass('login-return').text('Back to Login');
});

$('a.login-return').click(function() {
  $('.register-form').hide();
  $('.login-form').show();
  
  $('button').text('Login');
  $('a.login-return').removeClass('login-return').addClass('register').text('Register');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="login-form">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <div class="register-form">
    <input type="text" name="register-name" placeholder="name"><br/>
    <input type="email" name="register-email" placeholder="email"><br/>
    <input type="password" name="register-password" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <a href="#" class="register">Register</a>
</form>
```

Comment: The second click event wont be registered because at that time there is no element with class .login-return

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there is not element with `.login-return` class at the time of attaching the events you need to use event delegation like this

```
$('form').on('click', 'a.register',function() { ... });

$('form').on('click', 'a.login-return',function() { ... });
```

[Read more about event delegation here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Below is a demo

```js
$('.register-form').hide();

$('form').on('click', 'a.register', function() {
  $('.login-form').hide();
  $('.register-form').show();

  $('button').text('Register');
  $('a.register').removeClass('register').addClass('login-return').text('Back to Login');
});

$('form').on('click', 'a.login-return', function() {
  $('.register-form').hide();
  $('.login-form').show();

  $('button').text('Login');
  $('a.login-return').removeClass('login-return').addClass('register').text('Register');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div class="login-form">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <div class="register-form">
    <input type="text" name="register-name" placeholder="name">
    <br/>
    <input type="email" name="register-email" placeholder="email">
    <br/>
    <input type="password" name="register-password" placeholder="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
  <a href="#" class="register">Register</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that when you change the class on the button it loses it's event bindings. You can retain the event bindings by using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).